# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression data type nvarchar

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code to calculate weight, but when i run it i get

> arithmetic overflow error converting expression data type nvarchar

```
UPDATE T1 
SET [1 WO # WGHT] = CASE 
                       WHEN t2.[WEIGHT] = 'NMI' THEN 0 
                       WHEN t2.[WEIGHT] = '' THEN 0 
                       WHEN t2.[WEIGHT] IS NULL THEN 0
                       ELSE CAST(t2.[WEIGHT] AS float) 
                    END
FROM [PACKING SLIPS] T1
INNER JOIN inserted i ON T1.[AUTO PACK SLIP #] = i.[AUTO PACK SLIP #]
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT TOP 1 *
     FROM [WORKORDERS] T2
     WHERE T1.[1. WO #] = T2.[WORK ORDER NO.]) T2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error unable to convert data type nvarchar to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26765604/error-unable-to-convert-data-type-nvarchar-to-float)

Comment: What are the definitions of all tables involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the CASE expression with the following...

```
ISNULL(TRY_CAST(t2.WEIGHT AS FLOAT), 0)
```

If you're using an older version of SQL Server (2008R2 and earlier), the following Will work as well...

```
CAST(CASE WHEN t2.WEIGHT NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%' THEN t2.WEIGHT ELSE '0' END AS FLOAT)
```

Side note... You shouldn't ever use either the FLOAT or REAL data types to monetary values. If you don't want to use MOMEY or SMALLMONEY, consider using DECIMAL or NUMERIC.

Comment: i get TRY_CAST is not recognized built in function

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @user8066749 - Added code for older versions of SQL Server. Also see comments about the FLOAT data type.

Comment: Thank you jason  i tried `CASE WHEN isnull(t2.[WEIGHT],0)!='NMI' THEN CAST(CASE WHEN t2.WEIGHT NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%' THEN t2.WEIGHT ELSE '0' END AS FLOAT) else 0 end` but now i get `arithmetic overflow error converting expression data type nvarchar` error for the weight in `WORKORDER` table is `18.032` others looks good but just one workorder of weight `18.032`

Comment: Is there a reason why you should not ever use floating point data types in SQL? I agree you should not use them for fixed point values people enter in a decimal way in textboxes, for example, such as money. But what about measured real world data from some instrument for example, which gets provided to me as a float? Should I really convert that to `NUMERIC`?

Comment: No one ever said "never use FOAT  (or REAL)"... Of course they have their uses. Using them effectively simply requires that you know what are and what they are not. They are referred to as "approximate data types"  for a reason.